# Performance impact of NSString:characterAtIndex in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance

I am new to Objective C, coming from C++ & C# background. I need to do some string manipulation. As I need to operate at character level, I am concerned that making a function call for each character will be far too slow. E.g. in C/C++, when working with const char*, indexing is very fast. Is there any documentation that goes over the performance impact of methods like "charactersAtIndex"? Is the compiler smart enough to inline this method?

```
int current = 0;
NSString* str = @"....";//Long string
while (current < str.length && [str characterAtIndex:current] != ';')//function call at each character?
  ++current;
```

Comment: "I am concerned that making a function call for each character will be far too slow." - **you do not have the right to assume anything until you have done a benchmark to proof this.** I doubt this would be a bottleneck in your application. But if you benchmarked it, and it actually is, then grab a pointer to the C string (`str.UTF8String`) and use normal pointer arithmetic/indexing to access individual characters.

Comment: To loop over all characters, better use `enumerateSubstringsInRange:` with the `NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences` option. That is a nice block-based API and works correctly with all kinds of composed characters and surrogate pairs.

Comment: Back in the days before `NSJSONSerialization` I, like so many others, wrote my own JSON parser. I found that iterating over a C array of `unichar` made it take about a third as long as using `characterAtIndex:`. I also found that JSON deserialisation was a negligible cost either way.

Comment: No Objective-C method can be inlined by the compiler, but the runtime maintains a cache (per-class, I believe).

Comment: Of methods on NSString, `characterAtIndex` is probably one of the fastest (other than `length`, of course).  It is still quite a bit slower (at least 100x) relative to simply indexing a `char[]` as you would do in straight C.  (enumerateSubstringsInRange is a poor choice since it will create an entire new NSString object for each character.)

Comment: Note that character-based code is often the least efficient way to use NSString. For example, your code above could be replaced with a call to -rangeOfString: which would almost certainly be faster.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am building a library and this code may be used in many ways. Tommy, your observation (3x slower) gives me hope. This means that Objective C is only paying the cost of boundary checking and not the additional function call. I hope the 100x slower is incorrect, although it sounds about right, if the compiler doesn't inline. I agree with Greg about the Range functions. They require way more code, but it are likely to be faster.

Comment: @HotLicks, while reading char[] is fast, it does not handle Unicode correctly. When you start handling all those cases yourself, suddenly it's not so fast anymore. Do not assume that `enumerateSubstringsInRange:` has to allocate and destroy new objects. Apple is free to implement this in several ways that do not do that (just as they've reimplemented NSData to cleverly reduce memory copies). You still must profile before assuming that Apple's recommended solution (enumerateSubstringsInRange:) is slow.

Comment: I can assure you that enumerateSubstringsInRange would be significantly slower, and, worse, will create many more short-lived objects.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct, obj-c method calls are even more expensive than C++ virtual calls.

If you're concerned about the performance, you could query the length, then allocate buffer (depending on the expected length, either malloc or alloca), then call getCharacters:range: method to get C array of unicode characters in the string. Don't use UTF8String unless you're ready to link with something like IBM's ICU library to access individual characters.

Also, sometimes NSScanner class is helpful.

Comment: I'm not the person that gave you a negative vote but I will note: even `unichar`s do not necessarily correlate one-to-one with glyphs; they're 16 bits wide and unicode code points are up to 32 bits wide. Emojis are something you'll likely encounter where each one character occupies two unichars — e.g. if you're doing anything with a social media connection, regardless of whether you're localising for western use only.

Comment: @Tommy: That's probably why he mentioned the "... ICU library to access individual characters."

Comment: @MartinR he mentioned using that to parse UTF-8, which he cited as a more complicated alternative to using an array of `unichar`.

Comment: @Tommy, Apple's API like length and characterAtIndex doesn't handle surrogate pairs correctly. By using the approach I've described, topic starter will have the code functionally equivalent to the sample in his question.